# ES cluster node without load balancer

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have a 3 ES nodes cluster. all of them are data and master nodes. In my api (JAVA) i am using transport communication. I am using `xxx.yy.zz.aaa`  IP address to access/query the ES index. But i just wanted to know, If that `xxx.yy.zz.aaa` machine is down then i have to reconfigure the API to point to any one of the machine available in cluster. But is there a way to

1. how to utomatically detect the node failure and point query to other node ?
2. How to avoid this single point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

You should add all 3 IP addresses to your client, so it will connect to other node in case of one node failure. Your connector might look like this:

```
Settings.Builder settings =  Settings.settingsBuilder();
        settings.put("cluster.name", "elasticsearchcluster");
         List<String> hosts = new LinkedList<String>();
         ArrayList<ElasticSearchHost> esHosts = elasticSearchConfig.esHostsConfig.esHosts;
         for (ElasticSearchHost host : esHosts) {
            hosts.add(host.host + ":" + host.port);
         }
        settings.put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", "false");
        settings.put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", StringUtils.join(hosts, ","));
        //settings.put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts","xxx.yy.zz.aaa:9300, xxx.yy.zz.bbb:9300, xxx.yy.zz.ccc:9300");
        client =   TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();
        for (ElasticSearchHost host : esHosts) {
            ((TransportClient) client).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host.host, host.port)));

        }
        ClusterHealthResponse clusterHealth = client.admin().cluster().health(clusterHealthRequest().waitForGreenStatus()).actionGet();
```